# Cant access abd

Tags: usb-debugging

I cannot access abd on my computer it is quite annoying. I don't know what the deal is.

I have tried to modify the path variable on my system variables. It didn't work.
When I try to access it in cmd the command comes back "abd is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are calling the application by the wrong name. It is **ADB** not ABD. The message you posted from the console is when the file (or command) doesn't exist in the current directory (or in the environment path)

It stands for Android Debug Bridge.

Answer (score 2):

You might need to reboot after changing the system's PATH variables.

In any case, if you navigate to the directory where ADB is installed before issuing commands, you won't need to modify anything.

```
cd C:\AndroidSDK\platform-tools  
adb devices
```

This should work, assuming you installed the [SDK](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) to C:\AndroidSDK directory.